cut the video at certain time and add another video at end , repeat this whole process for full video and make every video has seperate video parts
I have two videos. If one video length is 42 minutes 35 seconds and another video length is 46 seconds, now I need to add this 46 second video after every three minutes 50 seconds so that the added video should be exported as a separate video. After every three minutes and 50 seconds, those 46 seconds of video should be added and a separate video should be exported. This should be done for a total of 42 minutes and 35 seconds of video. Does this happen in FFMPG?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It can be done.
It will require a small shell script.
#!/bin/bash

# change the inputs to the file names
input_file="your_file.mkv"
input_clip="your_clip.mkv"

mkdir -p temp concat && cd temp

ffmpeg -i ../"$input_file" -f segment -segment_time 230 -c copy ./"%02d_segment.mkv"

for segment in *_segment.mkv; do
        >concat.txt
        echo "file ./$segment" >> concat.txt
        echo "file ../$input_clip" >> concat.txt
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -c copy -avoid_negative_ts auto ../concat/"append_$segment"
done

cd ..
rm -rf ./temp

exit 0

Save as: clip_to_segments.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x clip_to_segments.sh
Put this script in the same directory as the two files.
Then, run it: ./clip_to_segments.sh
The segments are in the concat directory.

With -c copy you can only split at keyframes, which may not be exactly 230 seconds apart. Also, you can't use filtering with -c copy. Add a for-loop, and set -ss X*230 and -t 230 on the input

@Gyan I just figured it would -c copy with concat, I do it via file input all the time. (As it now uses.) Now, if closest keyframe is not sufficient, re-encode will be mandatory.
